# Placeholder value of input cleared on error

Tags: low-search

I have a Low Search form with two required fields, and am declaring these as required using the form tag's "required" parameter.

One field is an input connected to a jQuery date picker. The other is a checkbox list. Selecting the date, but not choosing one of the checkbox options, then submitting the form gives me the expected error message. However, the value of the date input is cleared out.

How do I keep the value chosen in the date picker after the error message is fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you don't. Low Search will redirect back to the form in the state it was before it was submitted (and before it was filled out). There's currently no way to retain the value that was submitted. I will make note of it as a Feature Request, tho.